# I am having trouble with an excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, formula-editor

I am trying to come up with a formula in excel that allows me to have two separate criteria from two separate lists and then sum the total amount of values that meet those criteria.  I can get the set of criteria to work, so
`=COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,[@[Sub ID]]` section allows me to see the amount of times a specific `supID` appears in column `A`.  However, the second part where I am trying to see after that how many times any value from a particular list of values appears in a separate list, does not work.

Is there any way to make a formula count one list of values against another list of values without having to name each additional value in the formula.

I could do this if I wrote,

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,[@[Sub ID]],Data!B:B,{"=apples","=pears","=bananas"[....]}))
```

But I don't want to have to write out each additional value, the list is too long.  I just want to have the list in a column so I can reference it in the equation but it wont let me.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,[@[Sub ID]],Data!B:B,Mapping2!B:B))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an iterative formula,  You want to limit the last criterion to just the data set:

```
Mapping2!B2:B15
```

Then use SUMPRODUCT which will force the iteration:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,[@[Sub ID]],Data!B:B,Mapping2!B2:B15))
```